# Create new node references for the node reference field

Tags: drupal

Is there a module besides http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate that allows a full from to be popped up/embedded to create a new node reference from a node reference field?

Comment: 'fraid not, but if you do find something I'd be grateful if you could post back on here, a module like that would be very very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the purpose of your question but this may be a workaround :
http://drupal.org/project/field_collection

If you are under D6 you can also try CCK 3.0 and its Multigroup submodule